# What jailbreak tweak will list only the songs of an artist or in an album I liked or hide all that I failed to like in Spotify?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, spotify

There is a junkyard bunch of your “liked” songs in Spotify, but what good is that if you can’t listen to, say, all your Michael Jackson records you liked!?

There is even a fake “liked songs” button which, oops, by mere happenstance is named the same as the liked songs (the thousands songs junkyard of yours) that you actually liked. That fake liked songs button inside any artist will show basically *popular* songs of that artist, songs that are *generally liked* but you may have never even heard of let alone liked or like.

There is no “[my] liked songs” or “[my] liked albums” within which you would also be able to list “[your] liked songs” and the same is true for artists.

We need “list liked” button inside every category, or a “hide [those not yet] liked”.

**Is there a jailbreak tweak to achieve either or both of these on iOS 14.3?**

Comment: This sounds more like a Spotify feature request than an actual question. Have you reached out to Spotify about this?

Comment: @nohillside apparently, Spotify has no interest to let you be your own music hermit. They need you to go out there, and listen to whatever it wants you to listen to. It used to be a feature then they took it away. On people’s complaint they pulled the most disgusting and cynical move to introduce the “[fake] liked songs button” to ease pressure while it does exactly what they wanted in the first place: When you think you open the right door, you’re out there where they wanted you to be: New songs you never were interested in, never liked, and are “popular”.

Comment: I disagree though, this is an inquiry into a functionality that Spotify clearly deliberately took away along with their financial interests, real or imaginary, but one that someone hopefully know under what name is implemented through privilege escalation and some tweaking around.

Comment: A hide button was implemented to half measure, but that (i) just defeats the purpose of the like button as now you have to tap through all the albums and artists you ever listened to, and hi hide on the 95% of songs of each artist you have songs you liked by, and albums you like in; (ii) it’s a game of “you-can’t-have-it-both-ways” since if you do that then you cannot, in any way, go through an album when _you_ decide to listen to an album you never heard all songs in, but have liked a few of so you gotta choose: Do I want to be able to listen to just those you like by hiding you don’t […]

Comment: and never listen to those you haven’t even heard (unless you manually tap song after song in the album or unhide the unknown songs) or I cave in and bend over and listen to everything as Spotify hopes (incl. post-album random songs, music advertisement), and not have any reasonable ways to listen to the songs I personally marked as “liked” or with 20 times more work made only visible by hiding the rest.

Comment: If Spotify removed the functionality from the app, no amount of tweaking will bring it back (especially not in a sandboxed environment and with code-signed apps like on iOS).

Comment: @nohillside Hm! Is that based on assuming Spotify would be able to verify that the app is intact or tweaked, and if it found its tweaked, it would not serve the app? If that’s so, that is the answer to the question. Sad (and will probably be infuriating too) though!

Comment: All apps are signed, iOS verifies that the app is not being tampered with before executing it. You may be able to re-sign it on a jailbroken phone but this then leaves the even bigger challenge of patching a binary to add missing functionality.

Comment: @nohillside Ok, that sounds better aligned with my previous understanding. Knowing the source code doesn’t seem way out of the world, there actually are tweaks to Spotify including such to its GUI — I though there would have been some methods for it to verify this particular thing is not tweaked as it seems to be at the crux of its business model. In that case, the question remains open for anyone knowing if there is such a tweak.

Answer (score 0):

One well hidden feature of the latest version as of October 3, 2022 is that one, instead of tapping on the search magnifier in Liked Songs I’m on the Home Screen, pulls down the screen and punched in the album title or the name of the artist.

It is easy to overlook and gravely misleading since who would think one can activate two different search bars in one iOS screen with greatly different scope of search.

This method allows that you have the songs listed out that meet the criteria entered (word of artist name or album name) in the order added to your songs.

Cons

- you can’t listen to a streak of songs in an album you liked m in the order they appear in an album unless you liked them in that order;
- you can’t listen to songs by a single artist across multiple albums let alone in their order they appear in their respective album unless you added them in that order;
- it takes some getting used to if you are tired or your attention is divided to find it even after you learned about it’s existence as it is highly counter intuitive and well hidden;
- you can’t simply reorder the songs in an album by unliking them and reliking them immediately as unliking them would make them disappear from the production upon the query word — you need to go into the album you wish to reorganize, unlike all songs and relive them;
- There are no quick reorder buttons based on genre (when an album or artist is associated with more than one), year, mood etc. as this is basically a work around half-measure left there possibly to diffuse bad press or antitrust law reasons; and
- Not the tweak one is hoping for reading this question.

Pros

- still better than absolutely not being able to listen to songs of your own liked songs listed by artist or album, have to create playlist thereof, or hide those you don’t like - it’s still all-in-all crap.